# Upload files to s3 bucket using python gives Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-2.7, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I created a Python script that should upload a file from my local ec2 to the s3 bucket

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
data = open('backupFile.txt', 'rb')
s3.Bucket('mlsd').put_object(Key='backupFile.txt', Body=data)
```

I went to AWS account details and got the credentials.

I executed `aws configure` to set credentials on my EC2.

Hear is the output of the credentials using `aws configure list`:

[image: Credentials]

I went to `.aws/credentials` and pasted `access_key_id`, `secret_access_key`, and `token`

I ensured that the token is not expired.

When I ran the script, I got the following output:

[image: Error]

Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: What are the permission on the IAM role you are using to connect to the bucket?

Comment: Where can I set it, and what should I configure on it?

Comment: You are using some credentails in your `.aws` folder. Where do they come from? If you write about a tokens and their expiration it means that you are using some IAM role. I don't know where did you take this role from. Thus my question.

Comment: I haven't set any roles. I got the credentials  from account details after login.

Answer (score 1):

Boto3 detects your credentials in possible locations, as described [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html), so it should find your access_key_id and secret_access_key

Make sure the user whose access_key_id you use has the access to S3 bucket.

I tried this code example and it works:

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
   """Upload a file to an S3 bucket

   :param file_name: File to upload
   :param bucket: Bucket to upload to
   :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified then file_name is used
   :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
   """

   # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
   if object_name is None:
       object_name = file_name

   # Upload the file
   s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
   try:
       response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
   except ClientError as e:
       logging.error(e)
       return False
   return True
```

Comment: Are you sure about the syntax? I am getting SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: Yep, there was a bug. Because Python does not use curly braces indentation and spaces are critical. Therefore, the return statement inside the function is different from when the return statement is mentioned outside. I fixed it.